# document.getElementById().textContent not working with numbers

Tags: html, typescript

Typescript

```
interface person{
    id: number;
    name : string;
    email : string;
    mobile : number;
    landline : number;
    website : string;
    address : string;
    
}
```

in this interface when value is updated to div , it is working for strings but its not working for numbers

Working ->

```
document.getElementById("detailName").textContent = people[id].name;
document.getElementById("detailEmail").textContent = people[id].email;
```

Not Working ->

```
document.getElementById("detailMobile").textContent = people[id].mobile;
document.getElementById("detailLandline").textContent = people[id].landline;
```

How ever if i add to current div value it will work , i.e

```
document.getElementById("detailMobile").textContent += people[id].mobile;
```

but i want to overwrite div

Answer (score 1):

It is because, `textContent`  accepts a string to set a text content of an element. Mobile being a number, it doesn't work. You can convert the mobile number into a string.

```
document.getElementById("detailMobile").textContent = people[id].mobile+"";
document.getElementById("detailLandline").textContent = people[id].landline+"";
```

It works by adding to current div, because you are concatenating a number to string (therefore, number gets converted to string ultimately).

```
document.getElementById("detailMobile").textContent += people[id].mobile; //string + number = string
```

Comment: Even better- `people[id].mobile.toString()` (Declrative code)